# Converting strings to number in large dataset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using this code to convert a large number of cells containing decimal numbers stored as text to decimal numbers:

```
For Each ws In Sheets
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If IsNumeric(r) Then r.Value = CDbl(r.Value)
    Next
Next
```

This operation **runs pretty slow** and I'd like it to run faster if possible.

I'm a beginner at this and the code displayed above is collected through google. Is it possible to make this operation go faster through editing the code or using a different code?

Comment: I'm no excel expert, but did find this for one sheet : ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value

Comment: @racraman: No that will not make a difference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your contents, you can quickly save some processing using

```
For Each r In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,xlTextValues)
```

Alternatively, move the range (or part of it if really big) into an array, (using `myArray=range("b2:x200")`), then process the array and rewrite it at once. This is much faster because in your sample the slow part is in fact the interaction between VBA and the cells.

```
Sub test()
    Dim src As Range
    Dim ar As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long

    Set src = Range("b2").CurrentRegion
    ar = src    'move ange into array
    For r = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(ar, 2)
            If VarType(ar(r, c)) = 8 Then 'string
                If IsNumeric(ar(r, c)) Then
                    ar(r, c) = CDbl(ar(r, c))
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    src = ar    'write array back to sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked straight away and fast too! Cheers @iDevlop

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This uses Array to do the entire operation. This is very fast as compared to looping through every range.

**Logic:**

1. Loop through the sheets and find the last row and last column
2. Identify the range instead of using `UsedRange` blindly. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)
3. Copy that data into array
4. Clearing the Sheet - Resets the format of the sheet to `General`. Hope you have no other formatting in the sheet? If you have then see second piece of code.
5. Paste the data back to the sheet.

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim usdRng As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim myAr

    For Each ws In Sheets
        With ws
            '~~> Check if sheet has any data
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                '~~> Find Last Row
                lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row

                '~~> Find last column
                lastcol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column

                '~~> Set your range here
                Set usdRng = .Range("A1:" & _
                Split(.Cells(, lastcol).Address, "$")(1) & lastrow)

                '~~> Write to array
                myAr = usdRng.Value

                '~~> Clear the sheet
                .Cells.Clear

                '~~> Write back to the sheet
                .Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, lastcol).Value = myAr
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**

[image]

**EDIT**

If you have other formats in the sheet then use this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim usdRng As Range, rng as Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim myAr

    For Each ws In Sheets
        With ws
            '~~> Check if sheet has any data
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                '~~> Find Last Row
                lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Row

                '~~> Find last column
                lastcol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                              After:=.Range("A1"), _
                              Lookat:=xlPart, _
                              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                              MatchCase:=False).Column

                '~~> Set your range here
                Set usdRng = .Range("A1:" & _
                Split(.Cells(, lastcol).Address, "$")(1) & lastrow)

                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = usdRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    '~~> Write to array
                    myAr = usdRng.Value

                    '~~> Clear the Range
                    rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"
                    Set rng = Nothing

                    '~~> Clear contents of the sheet
                    usdRng.ClearContents

                    '~~> Write back to the sheet
                    .Range("A1").Resize(lastrow, lastcol).Value = myAr
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but will this loop through each sheet in a workbook and convert everything to numbers, and thereby swapping formulas to number? How can the code be changed to run in only a selected sheet, in this case "Import"?

Comment: Yes this will loop through every sheet and convert numbers stored as text to numbers. Yes also it will convert formulas to text/numbers. To make it work for "Import" Sheet, remove the `For` loop and before the `With Ws` add a line `Set ws = thisworkbook.sheets("Import")`

Comment: It does'nt seem to convert decimal text to numbers in my case. I've uploaded a file to dropbox so you can check out the setup.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sntvcxpw5ntwc6f/test.xlsm?dl=0

It seems it has converted the format of the cells to "Number" but the numbers themselves stay as text after the script has run.

Comment: Do you have `,` as your decimal operator?

Comment: Yes, comma is decimal operator. Tried swapping out "0.00" to "0,00" with no effect.

Comment: when i replace "," with `.`, it worked as I wanted it

Comment: It worked in the file I linked in the comment above? When I change     rng.NumberFormat = "0.00" to "0,00" it still stays as text.

Comment: Yes it worked on the file linked in the comment above. BTW I replaced all `,` with `.`

Comment: Did you do a search and replace in the dataset? Isn't it possible to do a change in code to make it work automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Two other options, no VBA:

1. Turn on Error Checking if off, select the appropriate range, click the `!`, click Convert to Number.
2. Enter `1` in a cell, select and copy it. Select the appropriate range, Paste Special..., Operation multiply. (Will convert blank cells to `0`.)

Comment: I would be using that if this was supposed to be manual labor. I'm creating a workbook that collects data from another workbook and process that data, including converting text to number.

Answer (score 0):

turn the UI off and on.

```
'turn off UI
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

--- your code here

'turn on UI
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: No that will not make a difference. The code will still loop through cells which will make it slow :)

Comment: I know, but it was the fastest solution I had so far ;-) I also use this code and in my cases it improves the performances a lot.

Comment: In your case it may have helped because you had a very small dataset :) Try creating an excel file with 50k Rows and 1k Columns and then tell me how much time did it take. Your code will loop through `50000 X 1000 = 50,000,000` cells if all had numbers stored as text. Anyways, I leave the decision with you ;)

Comment: well at some point it is useful to move the excel macro to a database ;)

Answer (score 0):

My version - 
Set the range using your preferred option - I've just gone with UsedRange here, but would be better to use FIND (Siddharths code uses this).

I place the number 1 into a blank cell (I've used the last cell on the sheet), copy that number and paste special and multiply - any numbers will be multiplied by 1 and return a number, any text remains as

```
Sub TurnToNumbers()

    Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng = .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Place 1 into an empty cell, copy it and pastespecial and multiply.
        .Cells(Rows.Count, 1) = 1
        .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).Copy
        rng.PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
        .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).ClearContents
    End With

End Sub
```